Plotting a graph for inverse sine
I want to make a graph of the arcsine function using Mathematica. The following figure was created using GeoGebra:

What I've got so far is this
Plot[Evaluate[ArcSin[x]], {x, -1, 1},
PlotRange -> Automatic,
AspectRatio ->    1,
Ticks -> {Automatic, 
Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2,Pi/2]},
AxesLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black,Thickness[0.004]}]

The graph is

I got stuck actually on how to put arrows on the axes. Upon searching on the web, I was able to come up with the following code:
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.02}]

But as I inserted this code, the graph looks like this

I don't know how to fix this problem as the ticks, -Pi/2, Pi/2, -1, and 1 disappear.
Any help?

Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -1, 1},
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}],
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}},
 PlotRangePadding -> .5,
 Ticks -> {Range[-2, 2, 1], Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/2]},
 AxesLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"},
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}]

